# Why I am not able to start Activity on VirtualDisplay created in the same application?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to open an Activity in my application on VirtualDisplay to capture it and send to DIY hardware screen. VirtualDisplay is created normally, but I got a:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: igor.test, PID: 3197
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=igor.test/.Activity2 } from ProcessRecord{b7e2614 3197:ru.igor.test/u0a184} (pid=3197, uid=10184) with launchDisplayId=45
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3696)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1723)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5314)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5654)
    at igor.test.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:182)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.wm.SafeActivityOptions.checkPermissions(SafeActivityOptions.java:234)
    at com.android.server.wm.SafeActivityOptions.getOptions(SafeActivityOptions.java:125)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:1023)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:669)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1100)
```

I tried to change VirtualDisplay creating flags, and even got a MediaProjection service started, as it suggested in error description when I try to set flags to:
`flags = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION`

All this stuff run in a single Application, but error is still there...

Any suggestions ?